# There is already an object named 'cars' in the database-data

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, dbcontext, entity-framework-migrations

I am developing an MVC project using code first. I create my database using code first as you can see here :

```
public class DataContext:DbContext
{
    public DataContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

        Database.SetInitializer(
            new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, MigrationsConfiguration>()
            );
    }
    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Traffic> Traffics { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Validation> Validations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<File> Files { get; set; }
}
```

I uploaded my project in the company server, and they used my project and entered some values to database, so after sometimes I changed some columns in database, and I added normally in SQL design to database table, so I changed some part of my code too, and now then I upload my published file I get this error :

> There is already an object named 'Cars' in the database.

Note: I can't delete the database because I have data in it ,as i said I added the new columns to database, but my application can't connect to that database .

Migration part:

```
public class MigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public MigrationsConfiguration()
    {
        this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've got data in your production database already, don't use automatic migrations.  Your first priority is to get your databases in sync with your model.  How you do this will depend on how complicated your model is, e.g. how many tables.  My suggestion would be:

- Disable Automatic migrations
- Point your dev copy at a blank database, and create an initial migration
- Run Update-Database -Script to generate an SQL script for the migration
- Alter the script by hand so that it can be run on your production database
- Run this on your production database

Once you've got to this point, make sure you add migrations each time you want to make changes to your model, rather than making them by hand.